# Need help passing a string to Ajax post with Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to pass a hidden feild with jquery autocomplete however I cant seem to get the value and post it via ajax, possible a problem with val(), I have tried so many different ways of doing it its driving me bonkers

```
var nonce = $("#nonce").val();

   $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({ 
     source: function (request, response) {

       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url:"search.php",
         data: {
           term: request.term,
           nonce: nonce
         },
         success: response,
         dataType: 'json'
       });
     }
   }, {minLength: 3 });
```

Comment: have you console logged `nonce` ? Any errors in console?

Comment: You probably just need to move your first line inside the `source:` function as its probably setting the value prematurely

Comment: Any errors in the console? What is the result of `console.log(nonce)`? Are you running your jQuery code once the DOM has fully loaded?

Comment: Console shows the term is posted, if I was to change the nonce to a string like ```nonce:'123'``` it posts, and I get my php response for nonce posted.

Comment: console.log(nonce) is undefined

Comment: wrap you function under document.ready

Answer (score 0):

If this complete code block is inside document.ready, then `.autocomplete` should evaluate `$("#nonce").val();` every time it needs to post.
Because `var nonce = $("#nonce").val();` will be evaluated only once before attaching .autocomplete to '#birds', not every time you invoke autocomplete. So change your `data:` parameter of ajax as below,

```
data: {
    term: request.term,
    nonce: $("#nonce").val()
},
```